# Active MQ - Network of Brokers

Tags: activemq-classic

I have configured network of brokers with the topology as below.

- Producer(P1) connected to Broker(B1) and Producer(P2) connected to Broker(B2)
- Broker(B1) and Broker(B2) are connected as network of Brokers and are laod balancing
- Consumer(C1) connected to Broker(B1) and Consumer(C2) connected to Broker(B2)

Clients are configured to use the failover as:

- Consumer-1 = failover:tcp://localhost:61616,tcp://localhost:61615?randomize=false
- Consumer-2 = failover:tcp://localhost:61615,tcp://localhost:61616?randomize=false

Once Channel-2 goes down P2 and C2 shifts to Channel-1 which is the desired behaviour for failover.

I want to understand the behavior when Chaneel-2 come back?
I have noticed it is only Channel-1 which continues to serve all 
the connections even after Channel-2 has recovered and thus losing load balancing between Channels.

I want to know if it is possible once Channel-2 is back, load balancing will start automatically between channelsand respective Producer-2, Consumers-2 shifts to Channel-2 and thus giving full load balancing and full failover?

I have came across an article 'Combining Fault Tolerance with Load Balancing' on 
http://fusesource.com/docs/broker/5.4/clustering/index.html is this recommended for combining Fault Tolerance and Load Balancing?

Regards,

-Amber

Answer (score 4):

On both of your brokers, you need to setup your transportConnector to enable updateClusterClients and rebalanceClusterClients.

```
 <transportConnectors>
   <transportConnector name="tcp-connector" uri="tcp://192.168.0.23:61616" updateClusterClients="true" rebalanceClusterClients="true" /> 
 </<transportConnectors>
```

Specifically, you should want rebalanceClusterClients.  From the docs at http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html it states that:

> if true, connected clients will be asked to rebalance across a cluster
>   of brokers when a new broker joins the network of brokers

You must be using ActiveMQ 5.4 or greater to have these options available.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for posting, I did manage to configure brokers as mentioned above. I configured as (A)P1 connected to B1 and C1 connected to B1 (B)C2 connected to B2. (C)B1-B2 as network of Broker.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for posting, I did manage to configure brokers as mentioned above. I configured (1)P1 connected to B1 and C1 connected to B1 (2)C2 connected to B2. (3)B1-B2 as network of Broker. On start of the B2 I can see the balancing started between B1/B2. Once B2 goes down all connections shifts to B1. I want to understand if balancing is still valid if B2 comes back and C2 will consume messages from B2. How do I prove if balacing is taking place when B2 is back. Is there a way of logging Broker URI as discussed in the article ? http://activemq.apache.org/mdc-logging.html

Comment: You can monitor from JMX or look at the advisory messages for your brokers.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to your follow up question: 
"Is there a way of logging Broker URI as discussed in the article ?"

In order to show what client is connected to what broker, 
modify the client's Log4j configuration as follow:

```
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
                     xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    ...

    <logger name="org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport">
        <level value="debug"/>
    </logger>

    ...

</log4j:configuration>
```